# symfony2 textfield custom label

Tags: forms, rendering, symfony, twig

I had a little but unpleasant problem with symfony2 Field component. For example, I would like to output array of form fields in twig template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ form_label( field ) }}: {{ form_field( field ) }}
{% endfor %}
```

And here is text field configuration:

```
$field = new TextField( 'FieldName', array(
    'label' => 'MyCustomLabel',
) );
```

But unfortunately when engine renders this output i get 'FieldName' as label instead of 'MyCustomLabel'. I would not have problems if i outputting form fields not in for (in that case i can just add a label in template for each field). But the script doesn't know certain quantity and configuration of form fields before execution. So, I need to implement cycle method for field rendering. And I also want to stay in twig notation...I will be pleased for a good advise :)

Comment: Did you solve it? How can i set custom label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is added in Symfony2 beta2 http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-users/browse_frm/thread/c66165093665809

Comment: The link is no longer valid. It says: This group either doesn't exist, or you don't have permission to access it. If you're sure this group exists, contact the Owner of the group and ask them to give you access.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to change the label, than follow the steps.
1) Create form class.
2) `add('fieldName',null,array('label' => 'My New Label:'))`

please do not change fieldName, but you can play with Label within an array.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do it in template - pass the second argument to the `form_label`

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.email, 'Email:') }} <- this row
    {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

An answer for the Symfony 2.1 users who stumble onto this hoping for an answer, it's almost there is the @rikinadhyapak answer.

if you have extended the FormType class of some bundle like FOSUserBundle, in your buildForm method:

```
    $field = $builder->get('username');         // get the field
    $options = $field->getOptions();            // get the options
    $type = $field->getType()->getName();       // get the name of the type
    $options['label'] = "Login Name";           // change the label
    $builder->add('username', $type, $options); // replace the field
```

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly hold off on learning the Symfony Form component for a couple weeks. Symfony devs are doing a major-overhaul on the Form API. From what I understand, most of it is done, and a [pull request has been submitted to the main repository](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/399).

Answer (score 1):

For Symfony 2.3 you can replace the label using the events as the following:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $object = $event->getData();

    $field = $form->get('fieldname');
    $config = $field->getConfig();
    $options = $config->getOptions();
    $options['label'] = 'New label'; // change the label
    $form->add($field->getName(), $config->getType()->getName(), $options); // replace the field

});
```

but I would avoid this.